# Python Exceptions for when an if statement fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, exception, nested-if

I have a simple exception class:

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
    def __str__(self):
        return self.msg
```

I also have an if statement which I want to throw different exceptions from depending on what failed.

```
if not self.active:
    if len(self.recording) > index:
        # something
    else:
        raise Error("failed because index not in bounds")
else:
    raise Error("failed because the object is not active")
```

This works well enough, but nested `if`s for something this simple seem messy (maybe it is just me)... I would much rather have something like

```
if not self.active and len(self.recording) > index:
```

and then throw the exception based on where/how the if failed.

Is something like this possible? Are nested `if`s (in the first example) the way "best" to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

**Some libraries I am using require Python 2.7, therefore, the code is for 2.7

Comment: If you want the detailed error message then multiple if's is the way to go. Each `if` produces a unique thing, so its not overly chatty.

Comment: Use defensive approach !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a couple of nested `if`s look perfectly fine to me...

However, you could probably use an `elif` like this:

```
if not self.active:
    raise Error("failed because the object is not active")
elif len(self.recording) <= index:
   # The interpreter will enter this block if self.active evaluates to True 
   # AND index is bigger or equal than len(self.recording), which is when you
   # raise the bounds Error
   raise Error("failed because index not in bounds")
else:
   # something
```

If `self.active` evaluates to `False`, you'll be getting the error because the object is not active. If it's active, but the length of `self.recording` is less or equal than the index, you'll get the second error of index not in bounds, and in any other case, everything is fine, so you can safely run the `# something`

**EDIT:**

As [@tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) correctly points out in his comment, you wouldn't even need the `elif`, because when you raise an `Exception`, you exit the current scope, so this should do:

```
if not self.active:
    raise Error("failed because the object is not active")
if len(self.recording) <= index:
   raise Error("failed because index not in bounds")
# something
```

Comment: In this case, since the `if` unconditionally raises an exception, it doesn't matter if its followed by an `elif` or an `if`.

Comment: So much true, @tdelaney!! Very right, very right! **:-)** I edited the answer! Thank you

Comment: Did not even consider reversing my `if`s to exception calls so that nothing is nested. Simple, brilliant, no nesting. I like it! Thank you both!